# Convert For Each GridViewRow to Parallel.ForEach GridViewRow

Tags: vb.net, parallel-processing

I am trying to convert the code below into a parallel loop.  What is the proper syntax to use Parallel.ForEach instead of just ForEach?

```
    For Each grow As GridViewRow In gvEmployees.Rows
        SendSummaryReport(grow)
    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I used to get it working:

```
 Parallel.ForEach(Of GridViewRow)(gvEmployees.Rows.OfType(Of GridViewRow)(), (AddressOf SendSummaryReport))
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to do

`Parallel.ForEach(Of GridViewRows)(gbEmployees.Row, Function(grow) SendSummaryReport(grow))`

Comment: When I try that, I get this error:

Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'ForEach' can be called with these arguments:
    'Public Shared Function ForEach(Of TSource)(source As System.Collections.Concurrent.OrderablePartitioner(Of TSource), body As System.Action(Of TSource, System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState, Long)) As System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopResult': Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error.
...

Comment: @SchwartzE sorry forgot the Of TSource Part that describes the Type of Collection